# I have to optimize and reduce the performance for below mysql query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
SELECT income_range, count(*) AS count FROM

(SELECT CASE WHEN (income >=0 and income <= 250000) THEN 'range1' 

WHEN (income >= 250000 and income <= 1000000) THEN 'range2' 

when (income >= 1000000 and income <= 2500000) THEN 'range3'

when (income >= 2500000) THEN 'range4' END as income_range FROM subscriber_data,entities 

where exists (select * from entities where entities.id in (31) )  

and (subscriber_data.entity_uid = entities.channel_uid 

and subscriber_data.channel_id = entities.channel_id)

and Lower( subscriber_data.status) in ( 'active','expired') 

and Lower( subscriber_data.status) in ( 'active') )

AS INCOME_SUMMARIES GROUP BY income_range
```

output:-
income_range  count
range1         2796
range2          374
range3          749
range4           3079

Comment: To start, it would be helpful to post the output of the following commands: `DESCRIBE subscriber_data` and `DESCRIBE entities`.

Comment: Subqueries can often result in poor performing queries, btw.  You might be able to tell how bad this is by running `EXPLAIN [query]` where [query] is your whole query above.

Comment: Are you using plain sql or are you just using this as a part of a code (php, java, .net, etc?)

Comment: I am using Heidi Sql above query is back end query                For above query i need to reduce the count                                              Yes it is part of PHP

Comment: @ Mark For Describer subscriber_data it showing 6 columns (field,type,null,key,default,extra) 23 rows(id->key column is showing Unique key,msisdn-> primary key,status-> MUL,land_size->MUL,entity_uid->MUL                                                 For Describe entities (6 columns and 16 rows) (id->primary key,channel_id->MUL,channel_uid->unique key                        Explain query:- (10 columns and 4 rows) (select_type->primary,derived,derived,subquery) (table->derived2,entities,subscriber_data,entities)

Comment: Help me some one on this issue